# Onclick button doesn't function

Tags: javascript, html

i try to create a button when the page is load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function createButton(){
var newButton = document.createElement("button");
newButton.onclick="document.write('Tasto premuto')";
var textButton = document.createTextNode("Premi qui");
newButton.appendChild(textButton);
document.body.appendChild(newButton);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="createButton()">

</body>
</html>
```

the button is created succesfully, but the function that I have associated with onClick event doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: What do you want the button to do?  Where do you want `'Tasto premuto'` to be displayed?  You shouldn't be using `document.write`, it will erase your entire page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onclick` expects a function, not a string:

```
newButton.onclick = function() { document.write('Tasto premuto') };
```

Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCB5h/)

Of course, you should be aware that `document.write()` completely clears the DOM of all current content, rather than simply appending the string to the existing content.

Comment: thanks. I use document.write() with the purpose of clears the DOM. Why is not a valid solution write directly:

    newButton.onclick = document.write('Tasto premuto');

?

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a string to function pointer:

**Change:**

```
newButton.onclick="document.write('Tasto premuto')";
```

**To:**

```
newButton.onclick= function(){ document.write('Tasto premuto') };
```